# Convert PowerShell output to Python and store it in variable

Tags: python, powershell

Sorry in advance for silly question.

I am trying to write simple python script that runs virtual machine using PowerShell commands.

I have got a little problem with converting output from PowerShell command to a variable in Python.

The idea is:

I launch virtual machine, after that I check the state of it and, if the state is Running - start all the activity.

It is not a problem to do it in PowerShell, I wrote all the commands (launch VM, check state, if statement etc), but it is a problem to do it from py file.

My script looks like that:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os


class Utils(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ps_exec = r"C:\path\PsExec.exe"
        self.power_shell = r"C:\path\powershell.exe"

    def vm(self, apply_vm_script):
        subprocess.Popen([self.power_shell, apply_vm_script])

util = Utils()

def turn_on_vm(vm_name, checkpoint_name):
    apply_vm_script = 'Invoke-Command -Computername name -ScriptBlock ' \
                           '{ Get-VM ''"' + vm_name + '"'' | get-vmsnapshot -Name ' + '"' + checkpoint_name + '" | ' \
                           'Restore-VMSnapshot -Confirm:$false ; Start-VM -Name ''"' + vm_name + '"''}'
    util.vm(apply_vm_script)
    time.sleep(10)
    
def check_if_vm_on(vm_name):
    check_vm_script = 'Invoke-Command -Computername name -ScriptBlock { Get-VM | where {$_.Name -eq ' + vm_name + ' } | where { $_.State -eq "Running" } | select Name,State}'
    util.vm(check_vm_script)
    time.sleep(3)
    
def test():    
    turn_on_vm('VM_name', 'checkpoint_name')
    if(check_if_vm_on('VM_name')):
        Do my activity
    
def main():
    test()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, I can perform all if actions in PowerShell, but also can't convert bool output into Python:

```
if($State -like '*Running*') { Write-Output "True" }
```

State was defined earlier, no problem with variables.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Why... are you writing a Python script that runs PowerShell commands? Wouldn't it make sense to write a PowerShell script instead?

Comment: The main part of the script is Python commands. Only this in PowerShell. Its ok, just a bit easier for me.

Comment: You might be better off with writing a `.ps1` script file that does all those things and takes a couple of arguments (vm name, checkpoint name), so you can a) test or use it independently of your Python script and b) have an easier time running it from Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the stdout from the powershell script to your python program. This can be done with [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

```
def vm(self, apply_vm_script):
        p = subprocess.Popen([self.power_shell, apply_vm_script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result = p.communicate()[0]
        return str(result)
```

Also you need to return this value from `check_if_vm_on`

```
def check_if_vm_on(vm_name):
    check_vm_script = 'Invoke-Command -Computername name -ScriptBlock { Get-VM | where {$_.Name -eq ' + vm_name + ' } | where { $_.State -eq "Running" } | select Name,State}'
    result = util.vm(check_vm_script)
    time.sleep(3)
    return result
```

Then you will be able to check it with the if statement:

```
if(check_if_vm_on('VM_name') == "True"):
    Do my activity
```

Comment: Actually, I think I got it.
p = subprocess etc..?
Looks like it works, thank you very much.
Sorry, but can't vote.

Comment: Yes, sorry, p = subprocess. Fixed the answer